# Spring boot H2 create database schema from file

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an application that is running a H2 databse in memory POC purposes that I need to automatically import the schema.sql and data.sql scripts that are in my src/main/resources folder. From what I've read, placing these files in that folder is all that is required and when starting the server I can see they are being executed:

```
2018-09-30 14:01:45.644  INFO 9720 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/home/brandon/code/validus/music-web/target/classes/schema.sql]
2018-09-30 14:01:45.677  INFO 9720 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/home/brandon/code/validus/music-web/target/classes/schema.sql] in 33 ms.
2018-09-30 14:01:45.680  INFO 9720 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/home/brandon/code/validus/music-web/target/classes/data.sql]
2018-09-30 14:01:45.707  INFO 9720 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/home/brandon/code/validus/music-web/target/classes/data.sql] in 27 ms.
```

The problem is that when I then log into the schema, it is empty. Here is my JPA configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.validus" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
//      properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", "false");
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
//      properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "none");
//      properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action", "none");
//      properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source", "none");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

I've managed to turn off the generation based on the POJO's but I want it to automatically import the schema.sql still. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a sql folder so that you can put your sql scripts in it and try code in your datasource Bean like this:

```
 try {
            EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder dbBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
            return dbBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                    .addScript("Classpath:sql/security.sql").build();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Embedded Datasource bean cannot be created !!", e);
            return null;
        }
```

hope this helps